# How to structure SQL Statement to avoid so many joins

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, select

I am trying to build a select statement which will allow me to build a local in app cache when my application starts up. My table structure looks as follows;

[image]

I know to get some help I must demonstrate what I have already attempted but its extremely

I am using hibernate which should make things easier but I am really hitting a road block, the only approach I can think of is to select all the fields and then do a left outer join on the table ids matching, however the issue with this approach is that one user can have 0-1 business cards/ 0-1 social cards, 0-1 personal cards which means when i left outer join some of the data potentially might be missing for a user. The personalInfo/Logindetails and Device Data is all 1:1 mapping

Is there a more efficient way to do the select in hibernate which will allow me to easily construct my cache?

Ideally I would like to construct an object such that;

```
public class User {

    private BusinessCard businessCard;
    private SocialCard socialCard;
    private PersonalCard personalCard;

    private PersonalInformation personalInformation;
    private LoginDetails loginDetails;
    private DeviceData deviceData;


    public BusinessCard getBusinessCard() {
        return businessCard;
    }

    public void setBusinessCard(BusinessCard businessCard) {
        this.businessCard = businessCard;
    }

    public SocialCard getSocialCard() {
        return socialCard;
    }

    public void setSocialCard(SocialCard socialCard) {
        this.socialCard = socialCard;
    }

    public PersonalCard getPersonalCard() {
        return personalCard;
    }

    public void setPersonalCard(PersonalCard personalCard) {
        this.personalCard = personalCard;
    }

    public PersonalInformation getPersonalInformation() {
        return personalInformation;
    }

    public void setPersonalInformation(PersonalInformation personalInformation) {
        this.personalInformation = personalInformation;
    }

    public LoginDetails getLoginDetails() {
        return loginDetails;
    }

    public void setLoginDetails(LoginDetails loginDetails) {
        this.loginDetails = loginDetails;
    }

    public DeviceData getDeviceData() {
        return deviceData;
    }

    public void setDeviceData(DeviceData deviceData) {
        this.deviceData = deviceData;
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can make it a single table if it makes sense for you. However, you should first ask yourself if it makes sense for your business requirements. Aside, it is quite easy to map components using Hibernate so that though it is multiple objects in your class diagram, it may as well be represented by only one data table as they are two separate ways to model your business domain.

Comment: i mean ideally in java id love to have a pojo class which had all the above tables as objects in the one class but could i do a select in hibernate to generate that and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [**Hibernate Community Documentation - Charpter 7 - Association Mappings**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-intro):

> **7.2.1. Many-to-one**
>
> *A unidirectional many-to-one association is the most common kind of unidirectional association.*

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id" column="personId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="address" 
        column="addressId"
        not-null="true"/>
</class>

<class name="Address">
    <id name="id" column="addressId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
</class>

create table Person ( 
    personId bigint not null primary key
    , addressId bigint not null 
)

create table Address ( 
    addressId bigint not null primary key 
)
```

> **7.2.2. One-to-one**
>
> *A unidirectional one-to-one association on a foreign key is almost identical. The only difference is the column unique constraint.*

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id" column="personId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="address" 
        column="addressId" 
        unique="true"
        not-null="true"/>
</class>

<class name="Address">
    <id name="id" column="addressId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
</class>

create table Person ( 
    personId bigint not null primary key
    , addressId bigint not null unique 
)

create table Address ( 
    addressId bigint not null primary key 
)
```

This is how you may map one-to-one relationship. Notice this is the same sa `many-to-one` mapping, except for the `unique constraint`.

Now having mapped your classes, your `Person` class shall look like the following.

```
public class Person {
    public Address getAddress() { return address; }
    public void setAddress(Address address) { this.address = address; }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    protected void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    private Address address;
    private int id;
}
```

**To answer your question**

It all depends how you want the data to be persisted. As expressed, I would go with the identities of `BusinessCard`, `SocialCard` and `PersonalCard` into the `User` table so that one and only one card may exist per user.

```
<class name "User" table="Users">
    <id name="id" column="userId">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="businessCard"
        column="businessCardId"
        unique="true"
        not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="socialCard"
        column="socialCardId"
        unique="true"
        not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="personalCard"
        column="personalCardId"
        unqiue="true"
        not-null="true" />
</class>

<class name="BusinessCard" table="BusinessCards">
    <id name="id" column="businessCardId">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
</class>

<class name="SocialCard" table="SocialCards">
    <id name="id" column="socialCardId">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
</class>

<class name="PersonalCard" table="PersonalCards">
    <id name="id" column="personalCardId">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
</class>
```